# Hiding fields in a form based on selected input in drop down using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

We are trying to hide few fields based in the form structure based another selection in the same form field. Here the form is generated based on input from the user using loop (ng-repeat) and is not hard coded.

[image]

In the above image if the data source is chosen as S3 then the below two fields should not be visible. If it is chosen as Redshift then it should be visible.

```
<!-- Block Modified to get additional tag details -->
        <div ng-repeat="item in metadataGovernance">
            <awsui-control-group validation-message="" label="{{item.governance === 'Required' ? displayName(item.tag) + '*' : displayName(item.tag)}}">
                <awsui-textfield ng-hide="item.allowedInputs.length>0" name="{{item.tag}}" data-disabled="false" ng-model="item.value"></awsui-textfield>
                <select ng-show="item.allowedInputs.length>0" ng-model="item.value" class="awsui-textfield">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose one</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="input in item.allowedInputs" value="{{input}}">{{input}}</option>
                </select>
                <div class="hoverDesc awsui-button-icon awsui-icon question-circle" style="float: right;margin-left: -67px;margin-right: -28px;">
                    <span class="hoverDescText">{{item.description}}</span>
                </div>  
            </awsui-control-group>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Block Modified to get additional tag details -->
```

Comment: Can you show your json how it is?

Comment: Can you add some more code?

Comment: use ng-if / ng-show / Hide  ng-if="dataSource == 'Redshift'"

Comment: Show your full code...

Comment: metaDataGovernance is an array of objects which are displayed using ng-repeat, out of which some objects are displayed as drop down some as input text box. Here , upon selection of say, suppose "redshift"  certain objects should be hidden/disabled which are objects of metadatagovernance.

Comment: Okay @LavanyaD. Show your JSON object.. Then I can update my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a ng-show/ng-hide directive and give a condition like  `ng-show="item.value !== 'S3'"`

```
<!-- Block Modified to get additional tag details -->
<div ng-repeat="item in metadataGovernance">
  <awsui-control-group validation-message="" label="{{item.governance === 'Required' ? displayName(item.tag) + '*' : displayName(item.tag)}}">
    <awsui-textfield ng-hide="item.allowedInputs.length>0" name="{{item.tag}}" data-disabled="false" ng-model="item.value"></awsui-textfield>
    <select ng-show="(item.allowedInputs.length > 0) || item.value!== 'S3'" ng-model="item.value" class="awsui-textfield">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Choose one</option>
      <option ng-repeat="input in item.allowedInputs" value="{{input}}">{{input}}</option>
    </select>
    <div class="hoverDesc awsui-button-icon awsui-icon question-circle" style="float: right;margin-left: -67px;margin-right: -28px;" ng-show="item.value!== 'S3'">
      <span class="hoverDescText">{{item.description}}</span>
    </div>
  </awsui-control-group>
</div>
<!-- End of Block Modified to get additional tag details -->
```

Answer (score 1):

!-- Block Modified to get additional tag details -->

```
<div ng-repeat="item in metadataGovernance">
    <awsui-control-group validation-message="" label="{{item.governance === 'Required' ? displayName(item.tag) + '*' : displayName(item.tag)}}">
        <awsui-textfield ng-hide="item.allowedInputs.length>0" name="{{item.tag}}" data-disabled="false" ng-model="item.value"></awsui-textfield>
        <div ng-if="item.value == 'Redshift'">
            <select ng-model="item.value" class="awsui-textfield">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Choose one</option>
                <option ng-repeat="input in item.allowedInputs" value="{{input}}">{{input}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="hoverDesc awsui-button-icon awsui-icon question-circle" style="float: right;margin-left: -67px;margin-right: -28px;">
            <span class="hoverDescText">{{item.description}}</span>
        </div>
    </awsui-control-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-if

```
<div ng-repeat="item in metadataGovernance">
    <awsui-control-group validation-message="" label="{{item.governance === 'Required' ? displayName(item.tag) + '*' : displayName(item.tag)}}">
        <awsui-textfield ng-hide="item.allowedInputs.length>0" name="{{item.tag}}" data-disabled="false" ng-model="item.value"></awsui-textfield>
        <select ng-if="(item.allowedInputs.length > 0) || item.value!== 'S3'" ng-model="item.value" class="awsui-textfield">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Choose one</option>
            <option ng-repeat="input in item.allowedInputs" value="{{input}}">{{input}}</option>
        </select>
        <div class="hoverDesc awsui-button-icon awsui-icon question-circle" style="float: right;margin-left: -67px;margin-right: -28px;" ng-if="item.value!== 'S3'">
            <span class="hoverDescText">{{item.description}}</span>
        </div>
    </awsui-control-group>
</div>
```